# LinearLayout set border color dynamically using java code without XML

Tags: android, android-layout

I have done some research on that issue , but I have not found anything similar just yet.

First I make a border of Linear Layout using ShapeDrawable then I have try to set background color on LinearLayout but color is not set then I have comment two line of ShapeDrawable then after I have set the background color of Linear Layout but problem occur in border color.

That's value I have got through JSON of background color and border color.

I want to set that value dynamically Background color and border color of Linear Layout through java code.

Please Guide me.

Thanks

```
LinearLayout linearToAdd = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
linearToAdd.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
float d = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

  linearToAdd.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor((String)(mPod.getBackground())));

    switch(parentType){
    case LINEAR_LAYOUT:
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)(mPod.getWidth()*d),(int)(mPod.getHeight()*d));
        Log.d(TAG,"LinLay, W,H,T,L: "+mPod.getWidth()+", "+mPod.getHeight()+", "+mPod.getLeft()+", "+mPod.getTop());
        linearParams.setMargins(mPod.getLeft(), mPod.getTop(), 0,0);            
        linearToAdd.setLayoutParams(linearParams);

               ShapeDrawable rectShapeDrawable1 = new ShapeDrawable();
               Paint paint1 = rectShapeDrawable1.getPaint();
        //     paint1.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
               paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
               paint1.setStrokeWidth(3);

        //     linearToAdd.setBackgroundDrawable(rectShapeDrawable1);

               break;
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try doing it by GradientDrawable. I tried this one. Hope it might help you.

```
GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
drawable.setStroke(3, Color.BLACK);
drawable.setCornerRadius(8);
drawable.setColor(Color.BLUE);
linearToAdd.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

In your XML layout give android:padding="1dp" to linearToAdd.

Comment: how to do it only for one side of the layout ? like "left"

Comment: for that @SumeetDarade you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28579031/3940368

Answer (score 0):

overide on windows focuschanged listener like below

```
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)(mPod.getWidth()*d),(int)(mPod.getHeight()*d));
        Log.d(TAG,"LinLay, W,H,T,L: "+mPod.getWidth()+", "+mPod.getHeight()+", "+mPod.getLeft()+", "+mPod.getTop());
        linearParams.setMargins(mPod.getLeft(), mPod.getTop(), 0,0);            
        linearToAdd.setLayoutParams(linearParams);

        Bitmap bitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(linearParams.width, linearParams.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas=new Canvas(bitMap);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor((String)(mPod.getBackground())));

        Paint borderPaint = new Paint();
        borderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        borderPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor((String)(mPod.getBorder())));

        canvas.drawRect(linearToAdd.getLeft(), linearToAdd.getTop(), linearToAdd.getRight(), linearToAdd.getBottom(), borderPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(linearToAdd.getLeft()+2, linearToAdd.getTop()+2, linearToAdd.getRight()-2, linearToAdd.getBottom()-2, paint);

        Drawable linearToAdd_bg=new BitmapDrawable(bitMap);

        linearToAdd.setBackground(linearToAdd_bg);

    }
```