# Dynamcally creating a widget by using Java, without XML

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have this layout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="MyPackage.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:id="@+id/content_main">


    <TextProgress
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textprogress_day"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_border">
    </TextProgress>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to create dynamically **TextProgerss**(My widget) 
without xml

TextProgress class

```
   public class TextProgress extends ConstraintLayout {
        private TextView mTextView;
        private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

        public TextProgress(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            this.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

            initializeViews(context);
        }
.
.
.
```

I tried below code

```
    ConstraintLayout cl= (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_main);
            TextProgress tp=new TextProgress(this,null);
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams tpParams=new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            tp.setLayoutParams(tpParams);
            cl.addView(tp);
```

But **MATCH_PARENT** does not work right

and I don't know, how to create dynamically below atrribute

> android:background="@drawable/layout_border"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603751/set-width-to-match-constraints-in-constraintlayout

Comment: MATCH_PARENT work right for me. just when I use java, MATCH_PARENT does not work right

Comment: You don't add constraints

Comment: I added TextProgress to content_main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve part of the problem.
**MATCH_PARENT** problem solved
look below code

```
 ConstraintLayout cl= (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_main);
            TextProgress tp=new TextProgress(this,null);
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams tpParams=new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            tp.setLayoutParams(tpParams);
            cl.addView(tp);

    ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();

    set.constrainWidth(tp.getId(),ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT);
    set.constrainHeight(tp.getId(),ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);
    set.connect(tp.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT);
    set.connect(tp.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
        set.applyTo(cl);
```

the **border** problem is solved in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28559644/linearlayout-set-border-color-dynamically-using-java-code-without-xml)